# How to solve $2 - \sqrt{3}i + z^{3}=0 $?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have tried to solve this "problem" so that i have $z$ switched with $a+bi$. Then  after some hours of solving this riddle i have gain an enormous numbers of lines but with no solution.

$2 - \sqrt{3}i + z^{3}=0 $

$z=a+bi $

I want to know how much is a and b.

Comment: It would help if you could state exactly what the question is, rather than some string of symbols. Are you trying to solve for a value $z$ with a certain property? Do you want to express the first expression in terms of $a$ and $b$? What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: I see no equation to solve anywhere...

Comment: Okay, let's be clearer: you want the cube root of $-2+i\sqrt 3$?

Comment: I want to express a and b from upper equality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$z^3=-2+\sqrt{3}i$

Let's express $-2+\sqrt{3}i$ in form of $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$

$r=\sqrt{4+3}=\sqrt{7}$

$\theta=\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})+\pi$

so we may write that:

$z^3=\sqrt{7}(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$

Now if you apply [following formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Applications) you can calculate $a$ and $b$:

$z=\sqrt [3] {7}(\cos(\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3})+i\sin(\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3}))$ ,where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

so: $a=\sqrt [3] {7}\cos(\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3})$ and $b=\sqrt [3] {7}\sin(\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3})$

Comment: Thank you for solving this. You are life saver :D

Comment: Maybe replace some cubic roots by sixth roots and check some signs...